# How to print out an object if it's created with lambda?

Tags: java

Here is my interface example

```
public interface Card {
    String name();
}
```

I use it in ArrayList and create objects like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    cards.add(() -> "2");
  cards.add(() -> "4");
    System.out.println(cards);
}
```

How can I print a number to console if I create an object like this?
Here is the example of the printed text.

```
[d$$Lambda$14/0x0000000800bb1438@2d98a335]
```

But I want 2 and 4 to be printed out.

Comment: `cards.forEach(c -> System.out.println(c.name()));`

Comment: Or `cards.stream().map(Card::name).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628631/how-to-make-a-lambda-expression-define-tostring-in-java-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public interface Card {
    String name();

    static Card of(Supplier<String> supplier) {
        return new Card() {
            @Override public String name() { return supplier.get(); }
            @Override public String toString() { return name(); }
        };
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    cards.add(Card.of(() -> "2"));
    cards.add(Card.of(() -> "4"));
    System.out.println(cards);
}
```

output:

```
[2, 4]
```

Note: You can't override `toString()` method.

```
public interface Card {
    String name();

    public default String toString() {  // compile error
                                        // "A default method cannot override a method from java.lang.Object "
        return name();
    }
}
```